# Template sum of container elements (problems with value_type returned)

Tags: c++11, templates, stl, containers

this is an exercise from a previous c++ test I took:

Implement a template function *sum* which takes in a numbers *container* and returns their sum.
(Tip: if **C** it's the container type, the elements type is returned, for example, **from C::value_type**).

At the time of the test I wasn't prepared at all, but now, for a sum of a generic container I'd go like that:

```cpp
template<typename Iter>
double sum(Iter b, Iter e)
{
    double ret=0;
    for(;b!=e;b++)
        ret+=*b;
    return ret;
}
```

or

```cpp
template<typename C>
double sum(const C& cnt)
{
    double ret=0;
    for(auto it=cnt.begin();it!=cnt.end();it++)
        ret+=*it;
    return ret;
}
```

My question here is how can I replace the function return argument with the actual container elements type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typename C::value_type`:

```
template<typename C>
typename C::value_type sum(const C& cnt)
{
    typename C::value_type ret{}; // default initialization
    for(auto it=cnt.begin();it!=cnt.end();it++)
        ret+=*it;
    return ret;
}
```

Since C++14 you can use `auto` as return type of `sum` template:

```
template<typename C>
auto sum2(const C& cnt) // before calling check if cnt is not empty
{
    auto it = cnt.begin();
    auto ret = *it;   // deduce type by dereferencing
    for(++it;it!=cnt.end();it++)
        ret+=*it;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using C::value_type but I didn't put typename first and the compiler wasn't happy. Now it's ok